# Is there a way to prevent the pretty-print gem from triggering every time a model is instantiate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to prevent the pretty-print gem from triggering every time a model is instantiate? I find it annoying and would prefer to explicitly call the function. Also, how can i sort the attributes being printed out?

Comment: You mean while on the IRB console? You can add `; nil` add the end of your code, for example: `x = X.new; nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coincidentally I do not use pretty-print for those reasons. You should check out [snoop_dogg](https://rubygems.org/gems/snoop_dogg) instead (Full disclosure, I created snoop_dogg).

The gem sorts the attributes alphabetically, and puts them to the console in a similar fashion as pretty-print, but it does not do so automatically. You instead call 'snoop' on the model instance when you want to inspect it in a more human readable way.

Also, 'snoop' takes arguments in the form of model relationships. For example, 'User.first.snoop(:address, :comments)' would print the @user instance as well as that user's associated address and any comments associated with that user.

I think this is what you are looking for. Hope that help! Feel free to [contribute](https://github.com/ooftypop/snoop_dogg) too!